# Does singular cohomology commute with extension of scalars?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold. I want to know whether the singular cohomology $H^k(X,\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $H^k(X,\mathbb Z)\otimes \mathbb R.$ Here $H^k(X,\mathbb R)$ denotes the k-th homology of the cochain complex $Hom_{\mathbb Z}(C.(X,\mathbb Z), \mathbb R)$, where $C_{k}(X,\mathbb Z)$ denotes the singular chain group for each $k$.

I can see that I'll be done if I can prove that $Hom_{\mathbb z}(C.(X,\mathbb Z),\mathbb R)\simeq Hom_{\mathbb z}(C.(X,\mathbb Z),\mathbb Z)\otimes\mathbb R$, as then we would be done by the fact that exact functors preserve homology, and  $\_\otimes \mathbb R$ is exact. It is certainly true when each $C.(X,\mathbb Z)$ is finitely generated, but I'm not sure whether it is true in general. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up the universal coefficient theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true (at least not if you ask for the canonical map to be an isomorphism).  For instance, if $X=\mathbb{N}$, then $H^0(X,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ and $H^0(X,\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.  But the canonical map $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\otimes\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is not an isomorphism.  For instance, it is easy to see that if $(x_n)$ is in the image of $\varphi$, then the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of the numbers $x_n$ has finite dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$, so any sequence of real numbers which are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not in the image of $\varphi$.

(In fact, $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\otimes\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, since they are both $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$.  But there is no canonical isomorphism between them, and so it would not be reasonable to say "singular cohomology commutes with extension of scalars" in this case.)